# Typeahead skips async request when typeahead's value already asynchronized

Tags: asynchronous, typeahead.js, bloodhound

When i change typeahead's value and it's already asynchronized, the request not send, and it loads from the old response.

```js
$('#MyTypeahead').typeahead('val', 'something');// Send async request
$('#MyTypeahead').typeahead('val', 'something else');// Send async request
$('#MyTypeahead').typeahead('val', 'something');// loads from the first one
```

For some reasons i need to async everytime typeahead's value changes

Answer (score 0):

Undocumented, i had to clear remote cache every single search,
The **solution** is simply disabling cache

```
remote : { cache:false ...}
```